# Removing Little Snitch completely (Mac OS X Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, mac, cpu, uninstall, little-snitch

I uninstalled Little Snitch months ago. Or so, I thought.

When opening Console.app, I see something like this:

[image: A lot of LittleSnitchUIAgent entries!]

Here’s a textual log:

```
21/11/09 22:05:31   com.apple.launchd[1]    (at.obdev.littlesnitchd[10045]) Exited with exit code: 1
21/11/09 22:05:31   com.apple.launchd[1]    (at.obdev.littlesnitchd) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
21/11/09 22:05:33   Little Snitch UIAgent[10046]    2.0.4.385: m65968c1c
21/11/09 22:05:33   Little Snitch UIAgent[10046]    2.0.4.385: m579328b9
21/11/09 22:05:33   Little Snitch UIAgent[10046]    2.0.4.385: m41531ded
21/11/09 22:05:33   com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170]  (at.obdev.LittleSnitchUIAgent) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
21/11/09 22:05:41   com.apple.launchd[1]    (at.obdev.littlesnitchd[10049]) Exited with exit code: 1
21/11/09 22:05:41   com.apple.launchd[1]    (at.obdev.littlesnitchd) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
21/11/09 22:05:43   Little Snitch UIAgent[10050]    2.0.4.385: m65968c1c
21/11/09 22:05:43   Little Snitch UIAgent[10050]    2.0.4.385: m579328b9
21/11/09 22:05:43   Little Snitch UIAgent[10050]    2.0.4.385: m41531ded
21/11/09 22:05:43   com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[170]  (at.obdev.LittleSnitchUIAgent) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

Spotlight searches for ‘little snitch’ or ‘littlesnitch’ yield no results. Yet, it seems like I didn’t get rid of Little Snitch entirely, since it’s still using up my CPU.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried downloading Little Snitch again and running the Uninstaller?

[Little Snitch 2.2](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look in the following locations for plist files that look like they are related to Little Snitch. They will most likely start with `at.obdev` :

```
/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/System/Library/LaunchAgents
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
~/Library/LaunchAgents
~/Library/LaunchDaemons
```

Move the offending files to a different location, reboot and see if it fixed things.

Be very careful, especially with the /System locations, because if you remove the wrong file, it could harm your system.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to edit any files;  just unload the service and delete its plist:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/at.obdev.littlesnitchd.plist
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/at.obdev.littlesnitchd.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

You need open terminal:

```
cd /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd
```

make a backup copy of overrides.plist (make sure it is there using the *ls* command)

```
sudo cp overrides.plist overrides.bak
```

open overrides.plist

```
sudo vim overrides.plist
```

Look for any `Little Snitch UIAgent` entries and remove them. Save. Close. Reboot.
(this should also remedy the peruser entries too)

Check Console if there are any entries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I couldn’t find any matching entries in that file (I tried searching for ‘little’ and came up with no results at all). P.S.: The second step should probably read `sudo cp overrides.plist overrides.bak`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manually mess around with launchd, [Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/) is a a graphical editor for it. Unfortunately, development of it has ceased, but it still works fine, and it's open source.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove Little Snitch from a system that wouldn't boot (hence, couldn't use the uninstaller) and accomplished it by logging in to Single User Mode (hold down Cmd+S) then mounting the drive and running commands from a script posted at [apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56481/remove-little-snitch-via-script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56481/remove-little-snitch-via-script)

### Danger! my system had no data - you could mess yours up!

```
#Kill Little Snitch Processes
killall $NetworkMonitor
killall $UIAgent

rm -R /Library/Application\ Support/Objective\ Development/
rm -R /Library/LaunchAgents/at.obdev.LittleSnitchNetworkMonitor.plist
rm -R /Library/LaunchAgents/at.obdev.LittleSnitchUIAgent.plist
rm -R /Library/LaunchDaemons/at.obdev.littlesnitchd.plist
rm -R /Library/Little\ Snitch/*
rm -R /Library/Logs/LittleSnitchDaemon.log
rm -R /System/Library/Extensions/LittleSnitch.kext
rm -R "/Applications/Little Snitch Configuration.app"
```

Worked for me...

I found that using launctl alone wasn't enough - I guess the kext was still loaded, because I'd see `LS(4050) Little Snitch Start` in the verbose startup messages after I'd unloaded and rm'd all my /Library/LaunchDaemon/ scripts

Comment: PS.. this was on 10.8, not Snow Leopard, sorry